# Inline-block containers do not sit site by side, cause expansion of container

Tags: css, inline, grid-layout

Apologies, I have attempted to create a JS Fiddle replication, but the issue does not seem to occur in the JS Fiddle so I can only think it is a problem with the more general CSS on the page.

The JS Fiddle created does not show the error, but here it is anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/j2qxh9zg/

I am attempting to line up two elements side-by-side. They use `display:inline-block;` and have a width of `33.3%` and `66.6%`. The body has `font-size:0` set in order to remove any whitespace issues so I do not believe this to be an issue with the whitespace between containers.

```
<div class="grid one-third">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Something"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid two-thirds menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a name="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a name="#expertise">Our Expertise</a></li>
                <li><a name="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a name="#tech">New Technology</a></li>
                <li><a name="#contact">Get In Touch</a></li>
                <li>01483 746650</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I cannot seem to get the `.one-third` and the `.two-thirds` divs to sit side by side, despite them both being `display:inline-block;`

```
.grid.one-third{width:33.3%}
.grid.two-thirds{width:66.6%}
.grid{display:inline-block;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Live link, you can see the menu is at the bottom of the page (grey box) http://digitalshowcase.somethingbigdev.co.uk/

The nav container is 70px high. It should be 50px high. Both the inside elements are 50px high, yet the container expands. Why?

Comment: Well, 33.33 + 66.66 = 99.99, so there is still 00.01% space left.

Comment: @Vucko And? That doesn't explain the issue at all.

Comment: If you inspect the code you will see that they actually are beside each other...

Comment: @Tom they are but they are not aligned as they should be, hence the expansion of the container

Comment: @Francesca yes but you have to be careful about how you ask what you want. When you say expansion of container everyone expects the container to expand horizontally, while yours "expands" vertically thus what you should be really asking is why are your elements not aligned vertically

Comment: @Francesca you'll need to learn how `inline-block` works. To fix your issue, add `vertical-align: top` to the `.grid` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding vertical-align: middle; to .grid will do it.